# Area between $f(x)= \sqrt{16-x^2}$ and $g(x)= e^{x^2}-2$

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a problem to find the area enclosed by two function, $f(x)= \sqrt{16-x^2}$ and $g(x)= e^{x^2}-2$

[image]

So I set up the integral, but I don't see how I can solve it. The answer I found from my book only shows the exact value of the answer, but not showing steps to the integration.

How is this possible to integrate these function ? Their chain-rule parts are missing.

The Question [image]

The Answer [image]

Comment: If you *show* the integral that you set up, people can tell you whether you made a mistake in that step or not. In general, you should explain everything you've tried so far, so that you can get the best assistance.

Comment: It is not possible to express $\int e^{x^2}\,dx$ in closed form. Something is odd here.

Comment: $e^{x^2}$ has not elementary primitive

Comment: @user70944: Are you sure you wrote the functions correctly?

Comment: Yes, they're surely the correct function from the questions, that's why I found them odd to work it out.

Comment: You're not supposed to find a closed-form answer though; you only need its numerical value to within about 0.1ish so you can pick the right option in a multiple choice question (which is hardly an "exact" answer in pure mathematics). Divulging this sort of information is important when you ask questions.

Comment: To find that area, shouldn't we first find the integration of the functions, and then plug in the values ?

Comment: «find the integration of the functions» - do you mean [*primitive* or *antiderivative*](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Primitive_(Calculus)) of the functions? How are you going to do that if no such antiderivative is possible to write down in terms of elementary functions? Your vision is too narrow; we must resort to numerical approximation instead of wishing for a symbolic solution.

Comment: I don't understand how the textbook just suddenly come up with that answer value, and what's the numerical approximation you're referring to ?

Comment: The book probably just used MatLab or another CAS to evaluate the integral. Several methods. One includes Taylor Series.

Comment: Even finding the $x$-values of the points of intersection can only be done by numerical means. Surely the book must explain numerical methods for solving equations and for approximating integrals --- if not, the problem is crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $\sqrt{(4-x^2)}$. If you can use a TI-83 type calculator, graph $\sqrt{(4-x^2)}$ in Y1 and $e^{(x^2)}-2$ in Y2. Then you can use 2nd TRACE->Intersect to find the intersection (find the positive intersection). This stores the value in X. You can go to the home screen and store the X value in A using the STO key. Next, under the MATH key is the function fnInt, which finds the numerical integral. Use it to type the line $$fnInt(Y_1-Y_2,X,-A,A)$$ This will give you the value of ~5.050. (The Y variables are under the VARS key in the Y-Vars->Function menu.)